# Tweetings keeps to raise an exception

Tags: windows-7, twitter, .net-3.5

I have installed [Tweetings](http://www.tweetings.net/site/windows/) on my netbook running Windows 7 starter. It works fine, except that sometimes a dialog box about an uncaught exception appears, telling me that the configuration file has been written from another application, and reporting the name of the configuration file, which is in a directory created by the installer (the name of the file is "user.config").

The dialog box gives me two possibilities: to exit the application, or to continue to use it. If I choose to keep the application running, the same dialog box appears later, with a delay that changes all times.

What could it be the cause of this behavior? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is down to a badly written .Net application.

All you can really do is upgrade your version of the .Net framework (Check Windows Update)... However, this is most likely just down to the developer and I doubt there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: There was a pending update for the .NET Framework; once it has been installed, the application worked without showing the error message anymore.